# Relación muchos a muchos con Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, tablas, modelorelacional

Quería saber si alguien puede darme una mano con esto: estoy armando una base de datos relacional de cursos; hice la tabla cursos y ahora quiero agregar los días y horarios de los mismos pero me estoy trabando ahí y no sé como relacionarlos, primero había pensado hacer tres tablas "cursos", "días" (con los días lunes, martes, miercoles, etc.) y otra tabla "horas" con distintas horas, y a estas tres tablas relacionarlas en una tabla pivot, el tema es que creo que no puede haber una tabla con 3 fks o sí? Estoy usando Laravel y cuando quiero traer los datos relacionados con el método belongsToMany() no estaría pudiendo poner una de las tablas.
¿Alguien me puede dar una mano de como podría armar las tablas y relacionarlas?
La idea es que a los cursos tienen días de cursado y esos días tienen distintos horarios de ingreso y egreso.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Un pivote puede tener todas la FK que tú quieras, pero me parece que estás planteando mal el problema.

Digamos que tienes tu tabla de cursos

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cálculo |
| 2 | Álgebra |

La tabla días

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Lunes |
| 2 | Martes |
| 3 | Miércoles |

etc

Y la de horas

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8am - 9am |
| 2 | 9am -10am |
| 3 | 10am - 11am |

Y finalmente el pivote `horarios`, donde por ahora dice que Cálculo se imparte lunes y mércoles a las 8am y Álgebra los martes a las 9am

| id | curso_id | dia_id | hora_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

En el modelo `Cursos` pasarías por el pivote para declarar una relación `BelongsToMany` con los días

```
public function dias()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Dia::class, 'horarios', 'curso_id', 'dia_id')->withPivot(['curso_id', 'dia_id', 'hora_id']);
}
```

Y lo mismo para la relación con las horas:

```
public function horas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Hora::class, 'horarios', 'curso_id', 'hora_id')->withPivot(['curso_id', 'dia_id', 'hora_id']);
}
```

(estoy declarando el uso de `withPivot` para que sea más evidente mi explicación)

Con esas relaciones tú podrías traer los días y horas en que se imparte cálculo:

```
Curso::with(['dias','horas'])->find(1)
```

Y obtendrías

```
 [
   id => 1,
   name => 'Cálculo',
   dias => [
      [
        id => 1,
        name => 'Lunes',
        pivot => [
          id => 1,
          curso_id => 1,
          dia_id => 1,
          hora_id => 1
        ]
      ],
      [
        id => 3,
        name => 'Miércoles',
        pivot => [
          id => 2,
          curso_id => 1,
          dia_id => 3,
          hora_id => 1
        ]
      ]
    ],
    horas => [
      [
        id => 1,
        name => '8am - 9am',
        pivot => [
          id => 1,
          curso_id => 1,
          dia_id => 1,
          hora_id => 1
        ]
      ],
      [
        id => 1,
        name => '8am - 9am',
        pivot => [
          id => 2,
          curso_id => 1,
          dia_id => 3,
          hora_id => 1
        ]
      ]
    ]
 ]
```

Esa salida debe ser bastante cercana a lo que buscabas obtener, pero a mi criterio la información que brinda sirve muy poco. Por el camino de los días tanto como por el camino de las horas, tienes que cruzar por segunda vez con el pivote para obtener algo que conteste a la pregunta ¿En qué horario se imparte Cálculo?

---

#### Otro Planteamiento

Yo optaría por definir las casillas del horario en un conjunto finito de días y horas, que podrías llamar "módulos" tu tabla de módulos se vería (usando los mismos horarios y cursos anteriores)

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Lunes 8am - 9am |
| 2 | Lunes 9am - 10am |
| 3 | Lunes 10am - 11am |
| 4 | Martes 8am - 9am |
| 5 | Martes 9am - 10am |
| 6 | Martes 10am - 11am |
| 7 | Miércoles 8am - 9am |
| 8 | Miércoles 9am - 10am |
| 9 | Miércoles 10am - 11am |

Ahora tu horario se definiría como

| id | curso_id | modulo_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 7 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 |

Tu pivote sólo tendría 2 FK y definirías una sola relación `BelongsToMany`

```
public function modulos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Modulo::class, 'horarios', 'curso_id', 'modulo_id');
}
```

(ahora no necesito ningún dato del pivote. No contiene nada extra)

Y pedirías los módulos de un curso con

```
Curso::with('modulos')->find(1);
```

Obteniendo

```
 [
   id => 1,
   name => 'Cálculo',
   modulos => [
      [
        id => 1,
        name => 'Lunes 8am - 9am',
        pivot => [...]
      ],
      [
        id => 7,
        name => 'Miércoles 8am - 9am',
        pivot => [...]
      ]
    ] 
 ]
```

En donde no necesitas enriquecer ni cruzar información para responder a la pregunta ¿En qué horario se imparte Cálculo?.

---

#### ¿En qué caso sí necesitarías más FK en el pivote?

Dependiendo del problema que quieras modelar, que no es tu caso, podrías usar el pivote para asociar el profesor, y decir que los lunes Cálculo lo dicta el Académico A, y los miércoles el Académico B, quien además dicta Álgebra los martes.

Podrías usar el pivote para definir también que el la clase de Cálculo del lunes y la de Álgebra los martes se dictan en el Aula N°15, mientras que Cálculo los días miércoles se imparte en el Aula N°1, pero esto son sólo ejemplos hipotéticos y extenderse sobre el aula es, en el fondo, aular de más.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, voy a probar con la opción que me diste!